# Divs Overlapping: How to push one with position:absolute under the other when they overlap

Tags: html, css

I have two divs (the left one is an image) inside a wrapper that are meant to be next to each other, the div on the right being positioned absolute with right:0 and bottom:0 so it positions to the bottom of the div image on its left. The issue is, when the screen gets small enough the position absolute one overlaps the image. I have added a div that just occupies space in the wrapper and I've avoided the overlap, but now when you make the screen smaller the div goes under the image but it doesn't reposition itself right underneath; it shifts to the right. Here is an example on JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xbdsq7zj/

Here is the html:

```
<div class='ideaside'>  
  <div class='ideaphoto'>
      <img src='http://www.devsourcecodex.com/images/advertisingexamples/200x200.png'></img>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;  width:150px; height: 120px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class='ideainfo'>
      <p clas='glyphicon glyphicon-star unclickable'></p>
    <span>Followers</span></p>
    <p><strong>
      Phase 1
    </strong></p>
    <p>By <%= render @idea.user %></p>
    <i>2 hours ago </i>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
  <p class='doc'>
    <b>Brief:</b>
    t's not fallacious at all because HTML was designed intentionally. Misuse of an element might        not be  completely out of question (after all, new idioms have developed in other languages, as well) but possible negative implications have to be counterbalanced. Additionally, even if there were no arguments against misusing the <table> element today, there might be tomorrow because of the way browser vendors apply special treatment to the element. After all, they know that “<table> elements are for tabular data only” and might use this fact to improve the rendering engine, in the process subtly changing how <table>s behave, and thus breaking cases where it was previously misused.
  </p>
```

Here is the css:

```
.ideaphoto {
  float:left;
}

.ideainfo {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

.ideaside {
  position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

I'd like it to go to reposition so that it is directly under the image rather than next to some whitespace under the image. Is that possible without using Jquery collision detection?

Thanks.

Edit: I am using Bootstrap, and this is all taking place in col-md-4. The image is always 200px, but the text div's width is sort of variable depending on the user's name.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this. Can you say something about `.ideainfo `, can it have a minimum-width for example?  We need to know when the layout goes from image-text on one line to a vertical layout of image and text block below the image. Please expand your description, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think bootstrap's function, (assuming your using bootstrap for this because of the glyphicon) will be of use to you. You don't have to use float anymore because bootstrap will do it for you.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ideaphoto"> <!--If viewport is regular it will take up half of the page. But if viewport is smaller it will consume a row, thus repositioning the .ideainfo below it.-->
         <!--Enter your Image code here.-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ideainfo">
          <!--Enter your IdeaInfo here.-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Issue is, its in `col-sm-4`, and the text width is variable. The image is always 200x200px, though. Will this still work?

Edit: It doesn't work, actually. How would i do it with the configuration I said

Comment: Had you cleared your css? Because it may be overriding bootstrap methods. What doesn't work, all of it or the image adjusting itself?